# Can add-on providers access the code of my application in Heroku without my permission?

Tags: heroku

Can add-on providers see/access the code of my application in Heroku without my permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the addons API has [only a limited subset of Heroku API endpoints](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-for-partners#list-of-standard-platform-api-endpoints) it can access. None of those endpoints will give them your source code, and the addons don't run directly on your dynos.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the Heroku add-on implementation and if the add-on is using the Heroku Platform API that would allow you to access your source code.

I found in Heroku Partner API a Source endpoint that allows you to download source code so it might be possible to download your app code.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#source

I've created my own Heroku add-on https://elements.heroku.com/addons/knapsack-pro and from the add-on creator perspective, I can tell that I did not find any requirements or access levels for Heroku API so I believe any add-on provider could use Heroku Source API to access your code.

Comment: The Partners API only gives access to a *portion* of the Platform API. There's no way adding a random addon gives that addon access to your source code. "Add-on Partners can access **a subset** of the Heroku Platform API via OAuth. This subset is called the Platform API for Partners." https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-for-partners (see "List of standard Platform API endpoints")

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.